# What does this mean: ClassName<T> where T : class

Tags: c#, .net

I've got this class:

```
public static class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    ....
}
```

I understand `public` and `static` and `class` and `Repository<T>`,but I'm not understanding this:

```
where T : class
```

Is `Repository` extending or implementing `class`?  Or does the `: class` refer back to the type `<T>`?

**!!ALSO!!:**

And, if I have an abstract base class `DataAccessBase` that I want this class `Repository` to inherit, how do I do that?

Comment: It is a [Type Constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).

Comment: the declarations after `where T` refer to the `T` type. Also, you will instantiate it as any other generic class, the `: class` restricts the types to be reference types, not value types.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Comment: The thing is , that putting the exact title in [google](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=What+does+this+mean%3A+ClassName%3CT%3E+where+T+%3A+class&oq=What+does+this+mean%3A+ClassName%3CT%3E+where+T+%3A+class&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.106730.106730.0.107646.1.1.0.0.0.0.212.212.2-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.210.mu20ceGE3Zk) would have given all the inforamation you need quicker.

Comment: I probably worded the title wrong.  Please see the ALSO part.  "And, if I have an abstract base class DataAccessBase that I want this class Repository to inherit, how do I do that?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are restricting it to consumable via a `class` as generic parameter and not to be used with `struct` (**Value Types**).

if we don't apply the constraint of the `class` on `T`, it would be usable with `struct` too and here the author has limited this generic class to usable on with `T` parameter with a reference type i.e. `class` as type parameter.

For more details, please refer to the [MSDN docs on Type Constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).

Comment: ok thank you! So, if I wanted this class Repository to also inherit from an abstract base class, what would that syntax look like?

Comment: public class Repository<T> : DataAccessBase where T : class

Comment: @GhostTW is right, you can do the way he just showed